# Does EnumBuilder always create enum which are not CLS-Compliant ? How to make the enum CLS compliant?

Tags: c#, enums, cls-compliant, assemblybuilder

Below code sample generates TempAssembly.dll with an enum Elevation in it.

```
 public static void Main()
        {
            AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            AssemblyName aName = new AssemblyName("TempAssembly");
            AssemblyBuilder ab = currentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(aName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
            ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(aName.Name, aName.Name + ".dll");
            EnumBuilder eb = mb.DefineEnum("Elevation", TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(int));
            eb.DefineLiteral("Low", 0);
            eb.DefineLiteral("High", 1);
            Type finished = eb.CreateType();
            ab.Save(aName.Name + ".dll");
            foreach (object o in Enum.GetValues(finished))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1} = {2}", finished, o, ((int)o));
            }
        }
```

I referenced TempAssembly.dll and used the enumeration Elevation in another project(say project TestA). 
As I want the code to be CLS-Compliant I added the following attribute to the project TestA.

> [assembly:System.CLSCompliant(true)]

The code where I am getting warning is:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public Elevation Elev { get; set; } 
}
```

The warning

> Warning   1   Type of 'TestA.TestClass.Elev' is not CLS-compliant

I checked documentation on how to write CLS Compliant code but I am unable to do much as the enum is being created dynamically. Any suggestions , how can I make the enum CLS compliant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried marking the assembly as CLS-compliant?

```
ab.SetCustomAttribute(new CustomAttributeBuilder(
        typeof(CLSCompliantAttribute).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(bool) }),
        new object[] { true }));
```

You should be able to do the same on `eb` too:

```
eb.SetCustomAttribute(new CustomAttributeBuilder(
        typeof(CLSCompliantAttribute).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(bool) }),
        new object[] { true }));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you apply the `CLSCompliantAttribute` to you **TestA** assembly you also need to add the CLSCompliantAttribute to your dynamically created TempAssembly. Since the attribute is not defined on it, it is by default **not CLS Compliant**.

See also [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.clscompliantattribute.aspx) for more information:

> If no CLSCompliantAttribute is applied to a program element, then by default:
>
> - The assembly is not CLS-compliant.
> - The type is CLS-compliant only if its enclosing type or assembly is CLS-compliant.
> - The member of a type is CLS-compliant only if the type is CLS-compliant.

So you have two options. Remove the CLSCompliantAttribute from your TestA assembly or add the CLSCompliantAttribute to your TempAssembly.

Comment: Or a third option: remove the `Elevation` enumeration from the public interface of the TestA assembly. (This does not prevent it from being used internally.)